# Google Omniauth - Remember user authorization after finished session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am using omniauth for login and I'm wondering how I can store the user's credentials so that after they close the browser and the session has ended OR decide to log out -> they do not need to "Allow access" the next time they try to login.

I am using a combination of OmniAuth Google and Identity. I am not using Devise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your omniauth config file, add the following:

```
provider :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_KEY'], ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET'],
  {
    approval_prompt: 'auto'
  }
```

**EDIT:**

In the new version of the `google_oauth2` gem, the user authorization will be remembered by default. If you want the user to always have to authorize the login, then use the new `prompt` option:

```
provider :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_KEY'], ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET'],
  {
    prompt: 'consent'
  }
```

For more information read [the documentation](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2#configuration).

Comment: The correct way to accept an answer is by clicking ✔ and not upvoting ^^

Comment: Oh, sorry, I confused you with the OP. Indeed you can ehe.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the `user_id` as a browser cookie.  When a non-logged-in user with a cookie visits your site, lookup the auth provider for that user (Google in this case) and query the provider to see if the user is logged in there.

Alternatively, use Devise :)  It allows OmniAuth integration very easily through its [Rememberable module](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Rememberable).

Comment: To clarify - I want them to not have to re-authorize and go through the "allow access" part again if they end session OR log-out.

Comment: @murtali: You should have received (and stored) the user access token.  As long as the access token is still valid, Google will not need to ask the user to allow access regardless of whether they have a session with, or are logged into, your system.

Comment: @PinnyM where would one store this access token? If I have collection of "login with" buttons, how can I know which access token to use if the user is not logged in?

Comment: @mcl: The cookie should tell you (if present) which user is making the request and hence the access token you would use.

Comment: @PinnyM The part I don't understand is, when the request to sign in again is made and say the user has a cookie - how does omniauth google use that information to make the request? All omniauth does is give you a link for the user to go through. There is no return value to which you can provide user token information with.

Comment: @murtali, you can use a before_filter to check for the cookie - if it's there do a user database lookup (based on the cookie value) to determine the proper provider and access key (yes, you should have this information already in your database).  Then query the provider with the access key to check if it's still valid.  If it is, consider the user as already logged in - no need to present the user with a provider list.